# Move jcrop drag handles following image rotation by jquery rotate

Tags: jquery, rotation, jcrop

I'm trying to rotate an image which has jcrop applied to it using jquery rotate, similar to this post:

[Make Jcrop tracker not rotate when cropping a rotated image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062754/make-jcrop-tracker-not-rotate-when-cropping-a-rotated-image)

I basically have 2 buttons to rotate the image 90 degree clockwise and anti-clockwise

I can rotate the image and the crop area functions correctly but the inline styles for the dragbars is incorrect when the image has been rotated. e.g resize-n after being rotated 90 degrees should be e-resize so the correct cursor is applied.

Does anyone know how this can be updated upon rotation